# Linux find: How to exclude the ".snapshot" directory from find's results?

Tags: bash, centos6, find

I wrote a rsync script which uses `find` command to find all files which are older than 10 minutes and copies them to a remote server.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
print_log "------ Starting $0 -------"
find $filedir -name \*.gz -mmin +10 >> $varfile
for line in $(awk -F"/" '{print $4}' $varfile); do
  rsync -raPv --ignore-existing --remove-source-files --chmod=u+rwx $filedir/$line rsync://appuser@10.11.X.X/hpfiles/ --password-file /etc/rsync.passwd  
done
```

The problem I have is related to the find command, when running the script I get the following response while it hangs there and won't continue:

```
[appadmin@srv01 ~]$ /nfs/hadooper/rsync_hpfiles-lock.sh >> /var/log/rsync_hpfiles.log
find: File system loop detected; `/mass1/hpfiles_staging/.snapshot' is part of the same file system loop as `/mass1/hpfiles_staging'.
find: File system loop detected; `/mass1/hpfiles_staging/.snapshot' is part of the same file system loop as `/mass1/hpfiles_staging'.
^C^Z
```

I've tried the following things but to no avail:

```
find $filedir -name \*.gz -a ! -name ".snapshot" -mmin +10 >> $varfile
find $filedir -name \*.gz -a ! -type d -name ".snapshot" -mmin +10 >> $varfile
find $filedir -name -a ! -path "*/.snapshot/*" \*.gz -mmin +10 >> $varfile
```

How does my command should look in order to be able to exclude the `.snapshot` directory from the find command output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find $filedir -name .snapshot -prune -o -name \*.gz -mmin +10 -print` should do it.

Comment: The command now works in terms of displaying the files but the error is still shown

Comment: Sorry, I don' t have an environment where I can test that. Although if it only prints the error (and doesn't hang), maybe just re-directing stderr to /dev/null might be good enough.

Comment: While this excludes all folders below `.snapshot`, it does include the `.snapshot` folder itself. See [ShadSterling's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1028558/25092) for an option that doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Pruning the name `.snapshot` works, but I prefer to prune the path `/.snapshot`:

```
find $filedir -path "/.snapshots" -prune -o -name \*.gz -mmin +10 -print >> $varfile
```

Comment: Yes, this. using `-name .snapshot -prune` leaves the top level `.snapshot` folder in the list, but `-path /.snapshot -prune` doesn't.